# How to append html to table after tr with id using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a html table with few rows in it. Now I want to append a new row i.e. tr. I am generating a html for this.

```
html = "<tr><td>some html</td></tr>";
```

Then I am using following code to append this html to table.

```
jQuery("#matchTable > tbody:last").append(html);
```

This is appending to the table after last tr. I want to append after certain tr with given id i.e. in between rows.

Please help !!!!

Comment: You answered your own question in the title. Use `.after()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
jQuery("#matchTable > tbody:last").after(html);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Wsjud/)

Update

```
<table id="matchTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="i1">
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="i2">
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="i3">
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

then

```
var html = "<tr><td>some html</td></tr>";
jQuery("#i2").after(html);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pr4nM/)

Comment: Thanks But I dont want to append after last tr but say second last tr or after 4th tr then ? I will have the id of the row after which I want to append my html.